# Passing TYPE annotations to methods instead of marker interfaces

Tags: java, interface, annotations

**[ANSWER EDIT]:** Short answer is that what I'm looking to do isn't possible. My question is a little misleading. I learnt that the [Marker Interface](http://www.example.com) pattern is actually what I called the Marked Annotations in my question (since the annotation you're creating is actually an interface). And checks on that can only be made at runtime. So if you're looking to make a compile time check with annotations well it's just not possible. An empty interface is the only option. Check answer to see how to do it at runtime.

---

I'm trying to avoid using marker interfaces in favor of marked annotations. Basically I want a bunch of classes be marked with this annotation, and pass instances of those classes to methods that accept that *type*. Here is my code:

**MARKER ANNOTATION:**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Message {
}
```

**CLASS:**

```
@Message
public class MessageTypeA {
}
```

**METHOD:**

```
public class DatabaseWriter {
    public void save(Message msg) {
        //some code
    }
}
```

**CALLING CODE:**

```
MessageTypeA msgA = new MessageTypeA();
DatabaseWriter writer = new DatabaseWriter();
writer.save(msgA);
```

**However I get `Error:(78, 23) java: incompatible types: MessageTypeA cannot be converted to Message`**

I'm not sure if what I'm doing is possible, but I read that marker interfaces can be replaced with marker annotations. Is it not possible in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete example of your code?

Comment: @Aris_Kortex edited

Comment: Why can you not make `Message` an interface and extend MessageA?

Comment: Oh I can. But in reading around the internet it says that that's a marker interface (an interface with no methods). And that those can be replaced with marker annotations. I haven't worked with custom annotations much so I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to do is possible though.

Comment: I would suggest you to go with an interface for now because later on you can add methods to it and force implementations.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree. I might end up going with an interface anyways if I have no choice, but I won't do it because "I might need it in the future". I've made that mistake before (coding for future functionality), and it only ended up adding unused code in the codebase.

Comment: Check your imports if your IDE has automatically imported another Message, e.g. from the JavaMail-framework. As @isalgueiro already answered, annotations aren't used as classes, so `public void save(Message msg)` doesn't make sense very much.

Comment: That's what's weird. I'm actually importing the correct one. And IntelliJ even makes it yellow. I find it weird that IntelliJ would even let you specify an annotation as the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [marker interface pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) is a way of adding metadata to your program types or obbjects that is readable in runtime.

See for example hibernate implementation of this pattern. [Their `insert` method](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/internal/StatelessSessionImpl.java#L91) accepts a plain `java.lang.Object`, and is inside that method where the metadata from the various annotations is used.

So, following your example implementation, I'd go with something like this

```
public class DatabaseWriter {
    public void save(Object msg) {
        if (msg.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Message.class)) { 
           //some code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The original question starts with "I'm trying to avoid using marker interfaces ...", so this does not answer it.

Comment: `msg.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Message.class)`

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `MessageTypeA` and `Message` are unrelated in the class hierarchy.  A method call is legal only if the expression's type is a subtype of the formal parameter's type.

One way to establish a subtyping relationship is with an interface, as you already noted.

Another way to establish a subtyping relationship is with type qualifiers (expressed as type annotations).

**TYPE QUALIFIER HIERARCHY:**

```
   @Message
      |
 @MessageTypeA
```

where `@MessageTypeA` is a subtype of `@Message`, and `@Message` means an unknown type of message.  `@Message` is the default if no type annotation is written.

**LIBRARY**

```
public class DatabaseWriter {
    public void save(Object msg) {
        // some code that can run on any old message
    }
    public void saveA(@MessageTypeA Object msg) {
        // some code that is specific to MessageTypeA
    }
}
```

**CLIENT**

```
Object msg = ...;
@MessageTypeA Object msgA = ...;
DatabaseWriter writer = new DatabaseWriter();
writer.save(msg);  // legal
writer.save(msgA); // legal
writer.saveA(msg); // compile-time error
writer.save(msgA); // legal
```

There is no run-time overhead or representation:  the enforcement is done at compile time.

A tool that enables you to build pluggable type-checkers that enforce correct usage is the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/).  (Disclaimer: I am a maintainer of the tool, but it is a regular part of the development toolchain at Amazon, Google, Uber, etc.)

You can [define your own type system](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#creating-a-checker) in a few lines of code.  However, still [consider using Java subtypes rather than type qualifiers](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#faq-typequals-vs-subtypes).

Comment: Nope this doesn't work. Try it out. I didn't run it but definitely no compile-time errors